# in Symfony2, how to render a controller directly in a smarty template?

Tags: templates, symfony, smarty, render

I'm fairly new to Symfony and so far everything worked, except following:
I installed SmartyBundle to use Smarty template engine instead of the default Twig. It works well. But in [the Symfony book](http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_book_2.2.pdf?v=3) at page 79, they explain a very neat Twig function: the ability to embbed the result of a controller directly from a template.

I did not manage to make this work with Smarty, so do you know if that could be done, and how?

I suppose I can achieve the same result using the forward method to call another controler from my current controler, but in my opinion it offers much more factorization capabilities to use this render function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use Twig or get used to be missing a lot of useful features and have very little support with Smarty because very few people use it with Symfony. Heck, it's problematic to get help from the community even when using the Symfony's built-in PHP templates because most people use Twig.

The further down the road you go, the more problems you're encounter if you're not using Twig. For example, almost all 3rd party bundles provide Twig templates that allow you to customize them easily.

Comment: That's what I intuitively thinked when I read more on the Symfony book... Thanks for your answer though !

Answer (score 0):

smartyBundle do support a similar feature in {render} tag. check out [Actions Extension](https://smartybundle.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0.0/#actions-extension). Though with the current master at smarty bundle with symfony 2.3 there seems to be an issue regarding use of URI in the render tag.